# React, undefined this

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, inheritance, parent-child

I'm calling this function from a child component:

```
removeWorkout: function (workoutId) {
 return axios.delete('/delete', {
        params: {
          id: workoutId
        }
      }
  .then(function(response){
        this.componentDidMount();
  });
},
```

server deletes a record :

```
app.delete('/delete/:id?', (req, res) => {
  Exr.find({'_id':req.query.id}).remove().exec();
  console.log("server deleting")
  res.send("done")
});
```

But `this.componentDidMount` doesn't work, because this is undefined. Other functions work .

Comment: Try `.then((response) => {this.componentDidMount();})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a binding issue, you need to bind the `context` by using `.bind(this)` or use `arrow function`, `arrow function` will do this job for you.

Use this:

```
.then( (response) => {
      this.componentDidMount();
 });
```

or

```
.then( function(response) {
      this.componentDidMount();
 }.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this isn't working is because `this` gets rebound to your callback function:

```
removeWorkout: function (workoutId) {
 return axios.delete('/delete', {
        params: {
          id: workoutId
        }
      }
  .then(function(response){
        // "this" now refers to your function(response){...} callback
        this.componentDidMount();
  });
},
```

The way you resolve this issue is to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which retains the parent's scope (`this` will refer to your React component):

```
removeWorkout: function (workoutId) {
 return axios.delete('/delete', {
        params: {
          id: workoutId
        }
      }
  .then((response) => {
        this.componentDidMount();
  });
},
```

or by capturing `this` into a variable prior to entering your callback:

```
removeWorkout: function (workoutId) {
 var _this = this;
 return axios.delete('/delete', {
        params: {
          id: workoutId
        }
      }
  .then(function(response){
        _this.componentDidMount();
  });
},
```

As a side-note, **you really should not be manually trigger lifecycle methods**, it would be preferable to call `setState` which will trigger a component update.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that It would be better to use setState, but I have errs, when I'm trying this.setState(this.state)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `this` in JavaScript is a magic keyword which refers to the object a method was called on. This can cause a lot of issues when a method isn't called on the object you expect it to be. There's some in-depth content on how `this` works in JavaScript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

You can get around that by explicitly binding your function so that `this` always refers to the same object in it. To do that, you use [Function.bind].(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) If your function is named "function", you can do:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.function = this.function.bind(this);
}
```

However, in this case, you're using `componentDidMount`, which is part of the React component lifecycle, so you *probably* shouldn't bind it. An alternative is to use an arrow function, as arrow functions always have a statically bound `this`:

```
removeWorkout: (workoutId) => {
 return axios.delete('/delete', {
        params: {
          id: workoutId
        }
      }
  .then(response =>
        this.componentDidMount());
)}
```

By the way, calling `componentDidMount()` directly is usually a bad practice. You shouldn't directly call React lifecycle methods. Instead, you should extract the function you want to call and call it both in this method and in the `componentDidMount` method.